# Проводной интернет в телефоне через usb-адаптер без роутера

Tags: android, usb

Возможно ли с помощью адаптера RJ45 to USB type C подключить телефон не к роутеру, а к напрямую кабелю провайдера? Что надо сделать, чтобы такая схема заработала?

[image]

Comment: Зависит от провайдера, наверное? Если он выдаёт айпишник по DHCP, то наверное ничего не надо делать (впрочем, у меня нет под рукой адаптера, чтобы проверить правильность своего утверждения)

Comment: А, и да, некоторые провайдеры привязываются к MAC-адресу, так что перед подключением бывает нужно сообщить провайдеру правильный мак (впрочем, это уже не имеет прямого отношения к телефону и адаптеру)

Comment: @andreymal, привязки в mac-адроесу нет, PPPoE-соединение. Телефон работал с этой штукой от роутера, но от кабеля провайдера - нет. И логин с паролем вводить даже не предлагал.

Answer (score 0):

Теоретически можно.

В первую очередь нужно проверить ваше устройство на возможность поддержки этого в настройках. Например, это Samsung Tab-A. Путь может отличаться от рисунка. Если есть неактивный пункт Ethernet то можно попробовать, но не факт, что это заработает. Идеальный вариант идти с устройством в магазин и проверять на месте.

Я пробовал подключить планшет ASUS правда через Micro USB - Ethernet Adapter, у меня не заработало. Если у вас получится напишите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]